# Have Ubuntu 16.04LTS installed, wanted to install Windows 8.1, created a bootable usb but when I boot from USB, shows no operating system found

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed but wanted Windows 8.1, created a bootable USB, but when I boot from USB to install Windows, it shows, no operating system found...
What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1,*

Make sure about your 'created bootable USB'. Is it bootabe in true sense?

Try [this software](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiiooHTm9bWAhUGNI8KHUy9D18QFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Frufus.akeo.ie%2F&usg=AOvVaw1zD51RaDpfAvgj2HzK405d) for creating bootable USB from image file.

*Option 2,*

Check for boot sequence of your system in the BIOS.

This will help.